# Since 4.5.1 Eclipse update my .ear files are generated with a SNAPSHOT suffix in the filename

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a basic Maven knowledge and I am developing in a project that uses it to build ear packages.
It was working like a charm: the ear were being created (name format: project-name.ear) and and deployed in my local wildfly directory by the eclipse IDE.
Now I had to update my Eclipse from 4.5 to 4.5.1, but the ears are being build with the name format: project-name-SNAPSHOPT-X.X.X.ear) and the JDNI name for the beans also changed.

What do I have to set so my file name and module name do not have the SNAPSHOT.X.X.X suffix?

Comment: Which configuration are you in? (default, release, or custom) Can you post your current pom? and you could try adding `<finalName>project-name</finalName>` within the `<build>` tag of your pom.  However, this would prevent any version from displaying on your ear file.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post my pom. I will write in details soo, but I think JBoss Tools were somehow "guilty": they were setting the SNAPSHOT in the filename. After changing its config it worked. Unfortunately I do not know how it was set before (I don't know if it changed during the update)